# What does return 0 do in the code and why is the yywrap function written without a body?

Tags: yacc, lex

I AM USING BISON AND FLEX. 
What does return 0 do in case of the kcalc.l file that I have posted?
And I am not getting the use of yywrap without a body (i mean not literally but an empty body).The code is of a calculator without any variable managing and basic operations that can be done like addition subtraction multiplication division and handling of unary minus operator. I have been studying through the lex and yacc specifications but did not get any answer for the query I asked .

```
   Kcal.y

%{
   #include <stdio.h>
%}
%token  Number
%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc UMINUS
%%
    statement:  expression
                 { printf(" result = %d\n", $1);} ;
    expression: expression '+' expression
                 { $$ = $1 + $3;
                   printf("Recognised'+'expression\n");
                  }
               |   expression '-' expression
                  { $$ = $1 - $3;
                    printf("Recognised '-' expression\n");
                  }
               |    expression '*' expression
                  { $$ = $1 * $3;
                    printf("Recognised '*' expression\n");
                  }
               |    expression '/' expression
                  { if ($3 == 0)
                    printf ("divide by zero\n");
                    else 
                     $$ = $1 / $3;
                     printf("Recognised '/' expression\n");
                  }
               | '-' expression %prec UMINUS
                         {
                             $$ = - $2;
                             printf("Recognised paranthesized expression\n");
                          }
               | '(' expression ')' 
                      { 
                           $$ = $2;
                           printf("Recognised paranthesized expression");
                       }
               | Number { $$ = $1;
                          printf("Recognised a no.\n");
                         }
          ;
%%
   int main(void)
   {
     return yyparse();
   }
    int yyerror (char *msg)
     {
       return fprintf(stderr,"Yacc :%s", msg);
      }
     yywrap()
        { 
         }
 
kcalc.l
%{
   #include "y.tab.h"
   extern int yylval;
%}
%%
[0-9]+ {  yylval = atoi(yytext);
          printf("accepted the number : %d\n", yylval);
          return Number; }
[ \t]   { printf("skipped whitespace \n");}
\n      { printf("reached end of line\n");
          **return 0;**
        }
.    { printf("found other data \" %s\n", yytext);
        return yytext[0];
     }
%%
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return 0` notifies the end-of-input to the parser, so apparently the expression should be contained on a single line. The empty body of `yywrap` is just wrong. If you use `-Wall` with the `gcc` compiler it will give two warnings for `yywrap`:

```
kcal.y:54: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
kcal.y:55: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

The first one because no result type for the function is specified (K&R style C), so it is assumed it should return an `int`. The second warning because it lacks a `return` statement for such an `int`.

Since a newline terminates the input, the chances of `yywrap` ever being called are slim. But it will be called if the input does not contain a newline. If by sheer accident the (more or less random) return value of `yywrap` were to be interpreted as `0` the tokenizer would end up in an infinite loop of repeatedly calling `yywrap`.